# Azure CLI - az deployment group create - SubscriptionNotAuthorizedForImage Error

Tags: azure, azure-cli

In Azure when deploying via 'az deployment group create' I get an error since a few days.

The ressource group is created in 'West Europe' - Region

Here is my command:

```
az deployment group create --resource-group rg-UITest-$(Build.BuildId) --template-file WorkingCopy/hook/AzureDevOps/e5_setupvm_template.json --parameters WorkingCopy/hook/AzureDevOps/e5_setupvm_parameters.json --parameters adminPassword=$env:PASSWORD_FOR_VIRTUALMACHINE
```

With debug Flag I get the following information

```
2021-06-01T08:49:28.2629276Z DEBUG: cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies: Response content:
2021-06-01T08:49:28.2630595Z DEBUG: cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies: {"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"BadRequest","message":"{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"SubscriptionNotAuthorizedForImage\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The subscription is not authorized.\",\r\n    \"target\": \"imageReference\"\r\n  }\r\n}"}]}}
```

Here is the template.json imageReference:

```
                    "imageReference": {
                        "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsDesktop",
                        "offer": "Windows-10",
                        "sku": "rs5-pro",
                        "version": "latest"
                    }
```

Just a few days ago it still worked. I am not sure what has changed or what the problem is.

Here the full template:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "networkInterfaceName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "networkSecurityGroupName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "networkSecurityGroupRules": {
            "type": "array"
        },
        "subnetName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "virtualNetworkName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "addressPrefixes": {
            "type": "array"
        },
        "subnets": {
            "type": "array"
        },
        "publicIpAddressName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "publicIpAddressType": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "publicIpAddressSku": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "virtualMachineName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "virtualMachineRG": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "osDiskType": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "virtualMachineSize": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "adminUsername": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "adminPassword": {
            "type": "secureString"
        },
        "diagnosticsStorageAccountName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "diagnosticsStorageAccountId": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "diagnosticsStorageAccountType": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "diagnosticsStorageAccountKind": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "autoShutdownStatus": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "autoShutdownTime": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "autoShutdownTimeZone": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "autoShutdownNotificationStatus": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "autoShutdownNotificationLocale": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "autoShutdownNotificationEmail": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "virtualNetworks_rg_scaleset4_vnet_externalid": {
            "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/fdcf7f70-e042-4c2e-aff0-c933b9a44779/resourceGroups/rg-scaleset4/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/rg-scaleset4-vnet",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "nsgId": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]",
        "vnetId": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name,'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]",
        "subnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetId'), '/subnets/', parameters('subnetName'))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[parameters('networkInterfaceName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
            "apiVersion": "2019-07-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses/', parameters('publicIpAddressName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "ipConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "ipconfig1",
                        "properties": {
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[concat(parameters('virtualNetworks_rg_scaleset4_vnet_externalid'), '/subnets/default')]"
                            },
                            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                            "publicIpAddress": {
                                "id": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses', parameters('publicIpAddressName'))]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "networkSecurityGroup": {
                    "id": "[variables('nsgId')]"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[parameters('networkSecurityGroupName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2019-02-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "securityRules": "[parameters('networkSecurityGroupRules')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
            "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "addressSpace": {
                    "addressPrefixes": "[parameters('addressPrefixes')]"
                },
                "subnets": "[parameters('subnets')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[parameters('publicIpAddressName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses",
            "apiVersion": "2019-02-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "publicIpAllocationMethod": "[parameters('publicIpAddressType')]"
            },
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('publicIpAddressSku')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "apiVersion": "2019-07-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', parameters('networkInterfaceName'))]",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('diagnosticsStorageAccountName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "hardwareProfile": {
                    "vmSize": "[parameters('virtualMachineSize')]"
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                    "osDisk": {
                        "createOption": "fromImage",
                        "managedDisk": {
                            "storageAccountType": "[parameters('osDiskType')]"
                        }
                    },
                    "imageReference": {
                        "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsDesktop",
                        "offer": "Windows-10",
                        "sku": "rs5-pro",
                        "version": "latest"
                    }
                },
                "networkProfile": {
                    "networkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('networkInterfaceName'))]"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "osProfile": {
                    "computerName": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]",
                    "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
                    "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]",
                    "windowsConfiguration": {
                        "enableAutomaticUpdates": true,
                        "provisionVmAgent": true,
                        "additionalUnattendContent": [
                          {
                            "passName": "oobesystem",
                            "componentName": "Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup",
                            "settingName": "AutoLogon",
                            "content": "[concat('<AutoLogon><Password><Value>', parameters('adminPassword'), '</Value><PlainText>true</PlainText></Password><Enabled>true</Enabled><Username>', parameters('adminUsername'), '</Username></AutoLogon>')]"
                          }
                        ]
                    }
                    
                },
                "diagnosticsProfile": {
                    "bootDiagnostics": {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "storageUri": "[concat('https://', parameters('diagnosticsStorageAccountName'), '.blob.core.windows.net/')]"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[parameters('diagnosticsStorageAccountName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {},
            "kind": "[parameters('diagnosticsStorageAccountKind')]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('diagnosticsStorageAccountType')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[concat('shutdown-computevm-', parameters('virtualMachineName'))]",
            "type": "Microsoft.DevTestLab/schedules",
            "apiVersion": "2017-04-26-preview",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('virtualMachineName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "status": "[parameters('autoShutdownStatus')]",
                "taskType": "ComputeVmShutdownTask",
                "dailyRecurrence": {
                    "time": "[parameters('autoShutdownTime')]"
                },
                "timeZoneId": "[parameters('autoShutdownTimeZone')]",
                "targetResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('virtualMachineName'))]",
                "notificationSettings": {
                    "status": "[parameters('autoShutdownNotificationStatus')]",
                    "notificationLocale": "[parameters('autoShutdownNotificationLocale')]",
                    "timeInMinutes": "30",
                    "emailRecipient": "[parameters('autoShutdownNotificationEmail')]"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "adminUsername": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[parameters('adminUsername')]"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you use a different sku? Say `rs5-pro-g2`? Use this to get the list `az vm image list -f "Windows-10" -l westeurope --all -o table` And maybe even a different region while you're at it. Purely in an attempt to isolate the issue. From what I can see, it could be an Azure issue

Comment: The image did not exist any more as the answer suggested down below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its Normal this image is no logger available,
When having this type of issue try to create it via the web interface as you will have the available SKU

Note : the listed image via az command is not always up to date
`az vm image list-skus --location 'westeurope' --offer 'Windows-10' --publisher 'MicrosoftWindowsDesktop'`

Better use

```
  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsDesktop"
    offer     = "Windows-10"
    version   = "latest"
    sku       = "20h2-pro"
  }
```